# How to check long-runing queries in spring boot/postgresql application?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have a Spring boot application with Hibernate, connecting to a PostgreSQL database. After some time, some users experience a problem with slow requests or requests without any response.

I suspect some long-running SQL queries, but how can I check which queries run long? I would like to log down execution times of queries. I know `show-sql` parameter for Hibernate, but it doesn't display arguments for SQL statements, nor it doesn't log execution times. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log slow queries in hibernate by setting the property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=100
```

Also, if you want to log SQL statements with parameters, you can use:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: Is property `LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS` documented? I can not find any mentions in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_statistics_settings) about it.

Comment: @SternK you have all available properties in the class [`AvailableSettings`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java). I don't remember how I run into it, but most likely through this class, just checking out/analyzing what can be configured.